# How to place an iFrame around a form

Tags: html, forms, iframe

how can I place an iFrame around this form? On submit my button directs to a success page and I need it all to stay in one screen, hence incorporating an `iframe`. How can I achieve this?  I've never used them before and adding `<iframe> </iframe>` tags around the form just makes it disappear.

Here's my form:

```
<form action="#link">
    <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Enter your name"/>
    <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Enter a valid e-mail address"/>
    <input type="text" name="comment" required placeholder="Enter your comment"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: can't see the html. If you want it to stay in the same page, why not try ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the form code, including the code to redirect to your success page in a separate document - usually PHP, then add the iFrame of that document where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

An iframe is a tag that allows you to include a page inside another page. So, you have to link to another file, and you cannot put other tags inside it, as you tried.

To achieve what you need, you have to create a file, lets call it **your_other_file.php**, where  you have the code of the form, and the code of the sucess page.

in your main page, you put something like this

```
<iframe width="800"  height="600" src="your_other_file.php"></iframe>
```

depending of your purpose, you could prefer to send the form by ajax and update de div. but if you have no much experience, this approach is good enough.